# Alamofire get pdf as NSData

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, alamofire

I use this alamofire request to get a pdf file, i want to save it as NSData:

```
func makeDataCall(urlString: String, completionHandler: (responseObject: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    //Perform request
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, headers: ["Authorization": auth])
        .responseData { request, response, responseData in
            print(request)
            print(response)
            print(responseData)
            completionHandler(responseObject: responseData.data, error: nil)
    }
}
```

In the response i get this:

```
"Content-Length" = 592783;
"Content-Type" = "application/pdf";
```

However `responseData.data` is nil.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: The latest, for swift 2.0

Comment: The syntax [on their page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-data-handler) is different from yours, so I thought maybe you weren't using the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Editing my previous response, I read your question too quickly.*

To download a file like a pdf you should use **Alamofire.download** rather than **request**.

There's a section on it in the docs:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-a-file

just checked with some random pdf from the internet and this works for me just fine:

```
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://box2d.org/manual.pdf", destination: destination)
  .response { _, _, _, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("Failed with error: \(error)")
  } else {
    print("Downloaded file successfully")
  }
}
```

Comment: In Alamofire 4.4, Swift 3.1, this is now: `let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` and `Alamofire.download("http://box2d.org/manual.pdf", to: destination)`. Also, if I'm understanding it correctly, it looks like the response closure now just includes a single parameter: `response` (which has `response.error` as a field).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 use this code if you want to download a pdf

```
    let h: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/pdf",
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    ]
    //random document name
    let randomString = NSUUID().uuidString

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        documentsURL.appendPathComponent("\(randomString).pdf")
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }

    Alamofire.download("yourURL",method: .get,headers: h, to: destination).response { response in
        if let destinationUrl = response.destinationURL {
            print("destinationUrl \(destinationUrl.absoluteURL)")
        }
    }
```